# Implementing a lambda function inside scipy's solve_ivp() results in too many values to unpack

Tags: python, scipy

```py
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp

def myfunc(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h):
  t=a+2
  d=b+3
  return t,d

a=1
b=2
c=3
d=4
e=5
f=6
g=7
e=8

solve_ivp(lambda t,s:myfunc(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h),np.linspace(0,100),3)
```

This is the type of problem I'm facing. Scipy's `solve_ivp()` solves a function with the syntax `solve_ivp(function,timerange,initial guess,**kwargs)`.

I have a function (say `myfunc()`) that takes in a large amount of arguments, does some mathematical manipulation on them, and returns 2 variables. I've included a sample here. I want to make this function the reference for `solve_ivp()`. I've done it with `lambda` but I'm running into a `too many values to unpack (expected 2)` error.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: so the initial guess is 100 numbers, and the function takes just 2?  And it does even use those, returning 2 values derived from some globals?  It doesn't make sense to me!

Comment: @hpaulj the initial guess is 3, the timestamp comes first.

Comment: Retract that observation and look at the actual error - with traceback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is another case where I should have just asked for the full traceback, rather than making a quick guess as to the problem (see my comment).

Running your code:

```
   ...: integrate.solve_ivp(lambda t,s:myfunc(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h),np.linspace(0,100),3)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[9], line 15
     12 g=7
     13 e=8
---> 15 integrate.solve_ivp(lambda t,s:myfunc(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h),np.linspace(0,100),3)

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scipy/integrate/_ivp/ivp.py:524, in solve_ivp(fun, t_span, y0, method, t_eval, dense_output, events, vectorized, args, **options)
    519 if method not in METHODS and not (
    520         inspect.isclass(method) and issubclass(method, OdeSolver)):
    521     raise ValueError("`method` must be one of {} or OdeSolver class."
    522                      .format(METHODS))
--> 524 t0, tf = map(float, t_span)
    526 if args is not None:
    527     # Wrap the user's fun (and jac, if given) in lambdas to hide the
    528     # additional parameters.  Pass in the original fun as a keyword
    529     # argument to keep it in the scope of the lambda.
    530     try:

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

This is an unpacking error, in the

```
t0, tf = map(float, t_span)
```

This trying to get 2 float values the the `t_span` argument, and them in 2 variables, `t0,tf`.  Instead you supply a `arange(100)`!

Running it instead with (0,100):

```
In [12]: integrate.solve_ivp(lambda t,s:myfunc(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h),(0,100),3)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[12], line 1
----> 1 integrate.solve_ivp(lambda t,s:myfunc(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h),(0,100),3)

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scipy/integrate/_ivp/ivp.py:568, in solve_ivp(fun, t_span, y0, method, t_eval, dense_output, events, vectorized, args, **options)
    565 if method in METHODS:
    566     method = METHODS[method]
--> 568 solver = method(fun, t0, y0, tf, vectorized=vectorized, **options)
    570 if t_eval is None:
    571     ts = [t0]

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scipy/integrate/_ivp/rk.py:89, in RungeKutta.__init__(self, fun, t0, y0, t_bound, max_step, rtol, atol, vectorized, first_step, **extraneous)
     85 def __init__(self, fun, t0, y0, t_bound, max_step=np.inf,
     86              rtol=1e-3, atol=1e-6, vectorized=False,
     87              first_step=None, **extraneous):
     88     warn_extraneous(extraneous)
---> 89     super().__init__(fun, t0, y0, t_bound, vectorized,
     90                      support_complex=True)
     91     self.y_old = None
     92     self.max_step = validate_max_step(max_step)

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scipy/integrate/_ivp/base.py:135, in OdeSolver.__init__(self, fun, t0, y0, t_bound, vectorized, support_complex)
    133 self.t_old = None
    134 self.t = t0
--> 135 self._fun, self.y = check_arguments(fun, y0, support_complex)
    136 self.t_bound = t_bound
    137 self.vectorized = vectorized

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scipy/integrate/_ivp/base.py:17, in check_arguments(fun, y0, support_complex)
     14 y0 = y0.astype(dtype, copy=False)
     16 if y0.ndim != 1:
---> 17     raise ValueError("`y0` must be 1-dimensional.")
     19 if not np.isfinite(y0).all():
     20     raise ValueError("All components of the initial state `y0` must be finite.")

ValueError: `y0` must be 1-dimensional.
```

So now it doesn't like the scalar `3` for `y0`. Change that to a list `[3]` (or equivalent array):

```
In [13]: integrate.solve_ivp(lambda t,s:myfunc(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h),(0,100),[3])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[13], line 1
----> 1 integrate.solve_ivp(lambda t,s:myfunc(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h),(0,100),[3])

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scipy/integrate/_ivp/ivp.py:568, in solve_ivp(fun, t_span, y0, method, t_eval, dense_output, events, vectorized, args, **options)
    565 if method in METHODS:
    566     method = METHODS[method]
--> 568 solver = method(fun, t0, y0, tf, vectorized=vectorized, **options)
    570 if t_eval is None:
    571     ts = [t0]

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scipy/integrate/_ivp/rk.py:94, in RungeKutta.__init__(self, fun, t0, y0, t_bound, max_step, rtol, atol, vectorized, first_step, **extraneous)
     92 self.max_step = validate_max_step(max_step)
     93 self.rtol, self.atol = validate_tol(rtol, atol, self.n)
---> 94 self.f = self.fun(self.t, self.y)
     95 if first_step is None:
     96     self.h_abs = select_initial_step(
     97         self.fun, self.t, self.y, self.f, self.direction,
     98         self.error_estimator_order, self.rtol, self.atol)

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scipy/integrate/_ivp/base.py:154, in OdeSolver.__init__.<locals>.fun(t, y)
    152 def fun(t, y):
    153     self.nfev += 1
--> 154     return self.fun_single(t, y)

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scipy/integrate/_ivp/base.py:23, in check_arguments.<locals>.fun_wrapped(t, y)
     22 def fun_wrapped(t, y):
---> 23     return np.asarray(fun(t, y), dtype=dtype)

Cell In[13], line 1, in <lambda>(t, s)
----> 1 integrate.solve_ivp(lambda t,s:myfunc(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h),(0,100),[3])

NameError: name 'h' is not defined
```

Now we have a missing variable, `h`. Where's that supposed to come from?

Correct the global variable assignments:

```
In [17]: e=5; h=8
In [18]: integrate.solve_ivp(lambda t,s:myfunc(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h),(0,100),[3,3])
Out[18]: 
  message: The solver successfully reached the end of the integration interval.
  success: True
   status: 0
        t: [ 0.000e+00  9.384e-02  1.032e+00  1.042e+01  1.000e+02]
        y: [[ 3.000e+00  3.282e+00  6.097e+00  3.425e+01  3.030e+02]
            [ 3.000e+00  3.469e+00  8.161e+00  5.508e+01  5.030e+02]]
      sol: None
 t_events: None
 y_events: None
     nfev: 26
     njev: 0
      nlu: 0
```

Now it runs, though I'm not sure what good that is.  The function always returns (a+2,b+3), i.e. (3,5).  Which you integrate over the range (0,100), so the returned  `y` is the initial value + 100*(3,5), ie. (303, 503):

```
In [20]: 3+_18['t']*3
Out[20]: 
array([  3.        ,   3.28153316,   6.09686481,  34.25018124,
       303.        ])
In [21]: 3+_18['t']*5
Out[21]: 
array([  3.        ,   3.46922194,   8.16144135,  55.0836354 ,
       503.        ])
```

Your function returns 2 values, a function of globals `a` and `b`.  So `y0` also needs to be shape (2).  `solve_ivp` will a scalar `t`, and the 2 element `y` value, though your `lambda` throws those away.  I tried to use `lambda t,s: my_func(t,s,a,b,...)`, but kept having problems with it trying to return (t,[s+(2,3)]), a 'ragged array'.

I could use

integrate.solve_ivp(lambda t,s:myfunc(a,b,t,s,c,d,e,f),(0,100),[0,0])

putting `t,s` in slots where `myfunc` will ignore them.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of issues with your code.

1. The first two arguments of the differential equation function should be time and the dependent variable. Your `lambda` takes two arguments, `t` and `s` but never uses them.
2. You pass a `linspace` for the time range, but that should be a 2-member `tuple` or `list` containing the start and stop times. (If you want the results at specific times, pass the desired times to the `t_eval` `kwarg`.)
3. You pass an integer for the initial guess when it should should be an array (or `list`) of shape `(n,)` where `n` is the number of equations. That `n` should match the size of the differential equation return, but your differential equation returns two values and you only provide one initial condition.

You will need to address all of these issues for your code to work.